# Several rows update in DB2 v.8 z/OS

Tags: sql, db2

how can i update several rows in DB2 v8 z/OS (no merge function)

```
select a.Full_Name, b.Nick from 
tableA a join tableB b on a.id = b.id
```

I need that:
    a.Full_Name = b.Nick

As i understand i can't do like that

```
update tableA join join tableB b on a.id = b.id
set a.Full_Name = b.Nick
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a subquery:

```
update tableA a set a.full_name = (select nick from tableb b where a.id = b.id);
```

Comment: As a matter of fact, I believe this may be the _only_ answer available.